# Elasticsearch: group by global terms from query results

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm having trouble putting my goal here into words, so here's an example:

Example data

```
{ product_id: "1", color: "red", ... },
{ product_id: "1", color: "blue", ... },
{ product_id: "1", color: "blue", ... },
{ product_id: "2", color: "white", ... },
{ product_id: "2", color: "black", ... }
```

Let's say I'm querying for the color "red". I want to group **all** records by `product_id`, but only return the groups that have at least one record matching the query (color="red"). So in this instance, the result would look something like:

```
{
  product_id: "1",
  values: [
    { product_id: "1", color: "red", ... },
    { product_id: "1", color: "blue", ... },
    { product_id: "1", color: "blue", ... },
  ]
}
```

So even though not all of the `product_id: "1"` records have the color "red", they're all included in the group since at least one of them does, whereas `product_id: "2"` is not since it has no matching records.

I've been doing my best to come up with a solution from the docs, but no luck so far. Any help here would be very appreciated.

Comment: Or maybe the best solution is to just do a terms aggregation on `product_id` with the query, then use the multi-search API to resolve all the product records?

Comment: I think if you want to do the full thing in one query, it will be complicated. But if you can do this in 2 queries, the first one is to `term: {color: red}`, size 0, and aggregations on `product_id` to get the ids, then just use another `terms` query with all the ids you get from the first one to get them back. It's just the same as what you said above I believe.